# How do I change data on a specific instance of a React component?

Tags: reactjs

How do I update data on a specific instance of a component? Right now my `addOption` function is pushing elements to every instance's `options` array when really I just want it to update the particular instance I'm clicking on. As a result, it's rendering `option` components for every `question` component when I run the `addOption` method. Thanks!

```
// Quiz Builder Form

import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const QuizBuilderForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            questions: []
        };
    },
    addQuestion: function(id) {
        var questions = this.state.questions; 
        questions.push({ qtext : "", options: [""], id: this.state.questions.length, answer: "" });
        this.setState({
            questions: questions
        });
    },
    addOption: function(index) {
        var questions = this.state.questions;
        for (index = 0; index < questions.length; index++) {
            questions[index].options.push("");
        }
        this.setState({
            questions: questions
        })
    },
    handleSubmit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.questions);
        this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('quizzes');
        this.firebaseRef.push({
            question: this.state.questions
        });
        this.refs.form.reset();
        this.setState({
            question: [{ qtext : "", options:[""], id: 0, answer: ""}]
        });
    },
    handleChange: function(event) {
        // Do something
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.addQuestion();
    },
    render: function() {
        var questions = this.state.questions.map((question, index) => <Question key={index} index={index} ref={'question: ' + index} question={question} addOption={this.addOption} handleChange={this.handleChange} {...this.props}/>);
        return (
            <form className="quiz-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
                {questions}
                <button type="button" className="add-question" onClick={this.addQuestion} disabled={this.state.questions.length === 5}>{this.state.questions.length < 5 ? 'Add another question' : 'Question limit reached!'}</button>
                <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
            </form>      
        );
    }
});

export default QuizBuilderForm;

// Question component 

import React from 'react';
import Option from './Option';

const Question = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var options = this.props.question['options'].map((option, index) => <Option key={index} index={index} option={option}/>);
        return (
            <div className="question">
                <input type="text" value="" onChange={this.props.handleChange}></input>
                {options}
                <button type="button" onClick={this.props.addOption}>Add another option</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Question;

// Option component 

import React from 'react';

const Option = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter an answer here"></input>        
        );
   }
});

export default Option;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your `addOption(index)` method, you are not using `index` to update just the question you want, because at the `for` loop, it is iterating through all questions and adding an option to them.

I think that something like this would work:

```
  addOption: function(index) {
    var questions = this.state.questions,
        question = questions[index];

    question = Object.assign({}, question, {options: question.options.concat('')});

    questions = questions
                  .slice(0, index)
                  .concat([question])
                  .concat(questions.slice(index + 1));

    this.setState({
        questions: questions
    })
},
```

And change this in your `<Question />` component:

```
const Question = React.createClass({
  addOption: function () {
    this.props.addOption(this.props.index);
  },
  render: function() {
    var options = this.props.question['options'].map((option, index) => <Option key={index} index={index} option={option}/>);
    return (
        <div className="question">
            <input type="text" value="" onChange={this.props.handleChange}></input>
            {options}
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addOption}>Add another option</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

At your `addOptions()` in the `<QuizBuilderForm />` component, you're receiving an `event` parameter, but you want to receive the `index` of the question clicked. So, in order to do so, you could create a method in `<Question />` to handle the button event and call the `this.props.addOption()` with the correct parameter.

Try to avoid functions that would mutate state, so that's why I am using `Object.assign()`, `Array.slice()` and `Array.concat()` (things are a little bit easier with ES6+ spread operator over arrays and objects, so you could write `question = {...question, { options: [...question.options, '']`).

Comment: I'm getting an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined` error when trying this way. Would you recommend using Immutable.js ?

Comment: About the `Immutable.js`, I am still learning about it, but I found it really good to control the mutation of objects. It's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to add an 's' onto question in `.concat(question.slice(index + 1));` but after that it works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh, I see. I've changed the answer to correct what you pointed out.

Comment: Would I use this same process to get and change the input values for each rendered input?

Comment: I guess so, because that function is receiving just an event and you'd probably want it to receive the question's index and text. Please, if you think I have answered, consider accept my answer. ;)

Comment: I just noticed when implementing the `addOption` function, it doesn't update the `index`. Whenever you run the function the `index` stays at zero. Wouldn't this affect things like trying to get the value from a specific input since they would just be referencing the same index?

Comment: Do you have React DevTools installed in your Chrome? If so, try see for each `<Question />` component if the `index` prop is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry. The `<Question />` components are rendering fine. The index increases like it should. It's the `<Option />` components that are associated with each `<Question />` component who's index is not incrementing. I am trying to get the input values of each rendered `<Option />` component and am having some trouble and I'm wondering if this is why. I created a Codepen if that helps at all http://codepen.io/maxwellgover/pen/XjVpjE

Comment: In your `<Question />` component when you're declaring the `<Option />`s, there's  a  `{...this.props}`. When you do this, the `index` prop coming from `<Question />` is overwriting your `index={index}` prop declaration. If you need to pass props from `<Question />` directly to `<Option />`, you could move `{...this.props}` to be the first one.

Comment: Ahhhh. Ok thank you. I will keep that in mind for the future. Thanks so much.